# VBA input box with loop and step

Tags: excel

Hi I have the following code below which works but as you can see is very manual in terms of the loop until the input entry is correct.  Basically I want the code to check that the number the user has entered equals 19 or any row number from 19 with a step /increment of 7 e.g. 26,33,40 etc. up to a maximum of 1002 so in effect my validation range is 19 to 1002, with step of 7 from 19.  I have removed some of the myvalue code for the purposes of this post to reduce size.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
sub InsertRows()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Row1 As Long
Dim Row2 As Long
Dim myvalue As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim CancelTest As Variant
Dim Row As Range
Dim myPassword As String
 myPassword = "Password"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = 0
Do
myvalue = InputBox("Insert Rows Starting From Input Number:" & Chr(10) & _
                    "e.g. 19, 26, 33 (Multiples of 7)")
If StrPtr(myvalue) = 0 Then Exit Sub

If Not IsNumeric(myvalue) Then MsgBox "Numeric Values Only" & Chr(10) & _
                                   "Starting From Row 19 In Multiples Of 7"

Loop Until Val(myvalue) = 19 Or myvalue = 26 Or myvalue = 33 Or myvalue = 40 Or myvalue = 47 Or myvalue = 54 Or myvalue = 61 Or myvalue = 68 Or myvalue = 75 Or myvalue = 82 Or myvalue = 89 Or myvalue = 96 Or myvalue = 103 

If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

With Sheet1
    .Select
    .Unprotect Password:=myPassword

   ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Row1 = lastRow - 6
    Row2 = lastRow
    Rows(Row1 & ":" & Row2).Select
    Selection.Copy
End With

With Sheet1
    .Select
    Range("a" & myvalue).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    lastRow = 0
    .Range("c11").Select
    .Protect Password:=myPassword, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using the Mod Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164528(v=office.10))

`=Loop Until Val((myvalue - 19) Mod 7)) = 0`